# Sharepoint OnlineSearch - Omit results from a result source

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, search-scope, result-source

I want to get all the search results from the tenant except from a specific result source in SharePoint Online. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to remove a specific result source from all results directly. You can try to change your query text to contain adverse conditions with the specific result source.

Or, you can go to Center Admin->SharePoint->search, and click "Remove Search results", then type the URLs of the specific result source into it.

[image]
After the above, these URLs will be removed from search results.

Then go to Search Center, type "*", it will return all results except the removed URLs.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kally said you can specifically add those URLls to remove it from the Index.

If it is SharePoint On-Premises ,then you can use Crawl rules to exclude/include the contents from Crawl.

References:

[Manage crawl rules in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj219686.aspx)

[Create crawl rules](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/create-crawl-rule-in-sharepoint-2013/)